# Is there anywhere I can ask a question about reading raw memory?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I'm trying to reverse-engineer some Win32 calls, so when I say "reading", I mean **reading with my Mk1 Eyeball**.

I've got a block of memory which I think should be of a particular structure, but I'm not experienced enough to parse it - it doesn't match my expectations, so I need help.

I could ask this on SO, but it feels like it wouldn't be useful to anybody else - it's specific to my block of memory and the structure I'm trying to read. I could possibly twist it into a more general "how is memory laid out?" question with my block of memory as an example, but perhaps that's off-topic for SO?

Is there a "right" place for this question in the StackExchange network?

Comment: IMHO if it's related to software development (which reverse engineering of software definitely is), then it's a good fit for [SO]. Did you try asking it there? It's definitely *not* appropriate for [SU] or [SF].